# Avoid PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded when returning from DatePicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-8

How do I avoid the PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event when navigating back from the DatePicker(not necessarily using the back button)?

Comment: can you set a global variable boolean that indicates to bypass the contents of PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded when you dismiss DatePicker, or if DatePicker value is != null bypass method (within method)?

Comment: I don't believe so unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot avoid it. The loaded event is always called when navigating pages. When you use the DatePicker it navigates you from your current page to another page, then navigates back when you are done. Because of this you will always get the Loaded event.

There are many ways to avoid calling code that you need to load once. You can check the value of a static variable

```
private static bool _loaded = false;
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_loaded == false)
    {
        // do work
        _loaded = true;
    }
}
```

You can check the NavigationMode from the NavigationEventArgs to check if the page is being loaded fresh.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    {
        // Page has not been loaded yet!
        // do work
    }
}
```